# Using jQuery to fetch information from iframe from different domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm doing a site that fetches the stock property from a site and show it on my site.
But i'm having issue in displaying the it.

Here's the code :

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<iframe id="frame3" src="http://www.stockpart.net" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin " style="visibility : hidden "></iframe>

<script>
$(document).ready ( function(){
   $('#frame3').contents().find('.addClassClose').show();

});
</script>
```

I'm getting the following errors :

```
 AD BLOCK NOT DETECTED
pop.js:1 rt():in  true false tabunder 2
pop.js:1 rt():adv.bind  http://serve.popads.net/servePopunder.php?cid=242978
pop.js:1 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://stockpart.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.example.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Anyway is there anyway i can fetch information with the other site class/id using jQuery within an iframe?

Comment: **Uncaught SecurityError**: ***Protocols, domains, and ports must match.***

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Anyway, *The domain stockpart.com is for sale.* Is that domain the one you want to use?

Comment: @JuanRocamonde my bad , it's .net .. We're migrating server that's why I'm sandboxing it.

Comment: So you should first own the domain and be able to make changes in the server in order to make it allow your incoming iframe requests.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde , we're waiting for liquidweb to propogate the DNS .
We already own the stockpart.net

Comment: So why does it say uncaught securityError if the domain hasn't been propagated yet? I can not even load the page... :|

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer on the post posted by Patrick Evans with some modifications.

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://stockpart.net');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Then put the `iframe` on the main page to get the stock information

Comment: Sorry I thought it wasn't you the one answering your own question. My fault